# Creating and storing Google credentials in token.pickle from auth code

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

I am writing a program which uses a local `token.pickle` file to access the user's Google Calendar.

It runs on a server and what I want is for the user to be able to login through a web interface and then the server creates and stores the token.pickle file, created from the auth code the page sends back to the server.

Where I am at is that my Python backend receives the authorization code but I don't know how to create the token.pickle file from that... I know I need to exchange the code for the user's credentials though and I probably need to use the following snippets:

```
with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(creds, token)
```

and

```
# Set path to the Web application client_secret_*.json file you downloaded from the
# Google API Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = '/path/to/client_secret.json'

# Exchange auth code for access token, refresh token, and ID token
credentials = client.credentials_from_clientsecrets_and_code(
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata', 'profile', 'email'],
    auth_code)
```

Thanks, I would greatly appreciate any help.

**EDIT:**

Okay, so I would like to save some sort of way of getting the credentials or the credentials themselves from the access token, so I can access them from:

`service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)`

Can anybody clarify or give me a way to do this please?

Comment: The library should be doing that for you.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean? If it should be could you provide the code?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server - I think you may be approaching this wrong, you don't need a pickle, you need a flow object if your app is a server side application.

Comment: Hi, sorry, when I normally do `flow.run_local_server()` it produces some sort of credentials which are then

Comment: `with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
  pickle.dump(credentials, token)` but I want to generate these credentials from the auth code sent by the webpage to the server and dump those in to the `token.pickle`

Comment: Could someone help me please?